# What does it mean that gulp-ruby-sass doesn't work with globbing?

Tags: gulp-ruby-sass

Pretty simple here, I understand the basics of the statement, but how do I work around this? I use lots of file globbing in my sass.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is basically because of how gulp treats individual files within a stream. Since, gulp-ruby-sass is just a wrapper for Ruby sass, you just need to pass the correct params into the gulp-sass function namely: {bundleExec: true, compass: true, and require "sass-globbing"}. after that, they all play nice.